# cpprestsdk: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I have visited all the other questions but from what I see none are my issue.

Running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 on MacBook Pro 16GB memory Intel Core I7

I have ran brew doctor as well but don't see any issues that would cause this issue. Below is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(WebClient VERSION 0.0.0)

include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++14" COMPLIER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPLIER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPLIER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
else()
    message(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++14 support.
                    Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()

FIND_PACKAGE( Boost 1.62 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )

set(OPT_CPPFLAGS "-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/libiconv/include")
set(OPT_LDFLAGS "-v -lcpprest -lboost_system -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib -lcrypto -lssl")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OPT_CPPFLAGS} -v -g -O3 -fno-common -stdlib=libc++")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OPT_LDFLAGS}")

add_executable(anyExecutable webclient.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( anyExecutable ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )

include(CPack)
```

I used brew to install cpprestsdk/2.8.0 which also includes boost/1.62.0 and openssl/1.0.2j and libiconv/1.14.  My code is from a tutorial on wiki cpprestsdk.

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
#include <atomic>

using namespace utility;                    // Common utilities like string conversions
using namespace web;                        // Common features like URIs.
using namespace web::http;                  // Common HTTP functionality
using namespace web::http::client;          // HTTP client features
using namespace concurrency::streams;       // Asynchronous streams

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  auto fileStream = std::make_shared<ostream>();

  // Open stream to output file.
  pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream( U("results.xml") ).then(
    [=](ostream outFile) {
        *fileStream = outFile;

        // Create http_client to send the request.
        http_client client(U("http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/"));

        // Build request URI and start the request.
        uri_builder builder(U("thesaurus/xml/"));
        builder.append_path(U("ranking"),true);
        builder.append_query(U("?key"), U("--------------------"));
        return client.request(methods::GET, builder.to_string());
  })

  // Handle response headers arriving.
  .then( [=](http_response response ) {
    printf("Received response status code:%u\n", response.status_code());

    // Write response body into the file.
    return response.body().read_to_end(fileStream->streambuf());
  })

  // Close the file stream.
  .then( [=](size_t ) {
    return fileStream->close();
  });

  // Wait for all the outstanding I/O to complete and handle any exceptions
  try {
    requestTask.wait();
  } catch (const std::exception &e) {
    printf("Error exception:%s\n", e.what());
  }//try-catch BLOCK

  return 0;
}//Main
```

To save some space only printing some the errors they all the same in can't be found:

```
    [vscode] Executing cmake command: cmake --build /Users/gumpy/git-repos/webapi/build --target all --config Debug -- -j 10
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/anyExecutable.dir/webclient.cpp.o
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.11.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name webclient.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 274.1 -v -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=standalone -dwarf-version=2 -debugger-tuning=lldb -coverage-file /Users/gumpy/git-repos/webapi/build/CMakeFiles/anyExecutable.dir/webclient.cpp.o -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0 -I /usr/local/include -I /usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I /usr/local/opt/libiconv/include -stdlib=libc++ -O3 -std=c++14 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/gumpy/git-repos/webapi/build -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.11.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o CMakeFiles/anyExecutable.dir/webclient.cpp.o -x c++ /Users/gumpy/git-repos/webapi/webclient.cpp
clang -cc1 version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38) default target x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/local/include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/opt/openssl/include
 /usr/local/opt/libiconv/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
[100%] Linking CXX executable anyExecutable
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.11.0 -o anyExecutable -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib -search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names -lcpprest -lboost_system -lcrypto -lssl CMakeFiles/anyExecutable.dir/webclient.cpp.o /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.dylib -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::this_thread::interruption_point()", referenced from:
      boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&) in webclient.cpp.o
      boost::condition_variable::do_wait_until(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&, timespec const&) in webclient.cpp.o
  "boost::chrono::steady_clock::now()", referenced from:
      pplx::details::event_impl::wait(unsigned int) in webclient.cpp.o
  "boost::chrono::system_clock::now()", referenced from:
      pplx::details::event_impl::wait(unsigned int) in webclient.cpp.o
  "boost::detail::get_current_thread_data()", referenced from:
      boost::detail::interruption_checker::interruption_checker(_opaque_pthread_mutex_t*, _opaque_pthread_cond_t*) in webclient.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: This one [here] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153318/aid-in-building-boost-asio-ssl-example also helped but still missing something

Comment: Just add `thread` library to your `find_package` call, like so `find_package(Boost 1.62 COMPONENTS program_options thread REQUIRED)` and use targets instead `${Boost_LIBRARIES}`, like so `target_link_libraries(anyExecutable PUBLIC Boost::program_options Boost::thread)`. It should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The missing symbol names was due to a missing library. The necessary `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` are:

```
CPPFLAGS = -stdlib=libc++
LDFLAGS = -lcpprest -lboost_system -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_chrono-mt -lssl -lcrypto
```

Thanks so much for everyone's help.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as being correct! :)

Comment: Being a newbie here it won't do that for 2 days.  Oh well :)

Comment: @AmazingGrace - Boost depends on OpenSSL, so OpenSSL libraries must follow Boost libraries (or Boost libraries must precede OpenSSL libraries). Tending to order is necessary because LD is a single pass linker. Also see [Linking libcrypto in GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18872992/608639).

Comment: Well my reputation got to 16 yea!

Comment: @jww didn't mean to order on my answer just the list but I will rearrange it thanks for the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752559/1250473) may be the same issue you have, with the answer being link against `-lcrypto`.

Edit: Your problem is that you're trying to build a program that needs to be linked against other "libraries" - that is, other pieces of code that are usually pre-compiled - that are somewhere on your system, and which define "symbols," which is basically another way of saying variables or function names.

You let the compiler know which libraries you need by including arguments to the compile command that signify what you need to be linked with - in this case, your first few issues went away because you linked with -lcrypto, and from then on your code was able to find the 'symbols' - that is, variables and function names - that were previously 'undefined.'

For the rest of your issues, where you added 'lcrypto,' try using the arguments from [this wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/How-to-build-for-Linux) on building cpprestsdk on Linux. The flags appear to be:

```
-lboost_system -lssl -lcpprest -lboost_chrono
```

Last, but not least, have you follow the instructions for building this software on mac OSX on [their site?](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/How-to-build-for-Mac-OS-X) It might save you a lot of pain! :)

Edit: added a few more.

Comment: That clean some of them here is the rest:

Comment: @AmazingGrace: no additional text was posted after you said "here is the rest:" That said, you should first try googling the errors you're getting now, especially since I was able to find an answer to your first question already having been answered on this site :)

Comment: It wouldn't fix so I updated the main display.  Yes of bing these thousand times trying a dozen things nothing working even saw your suggestion but it doesn't cure the whole issue.

Comment: Yes I was at that site but it doesn't tell you the library names.  I build it and tested. Also deleted it and use the brew -install cpprestsdk instead.

Comment: added -lcpprest that cleaned up a lot. Down to 4 symbols I will update my question with the results.

Answer (score 1):

***Original Question***:

```
  "web::uri_builder::append_path(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool)", referenced from:
      std::__1::__function::__func<main::$_0, std::__1::allocator<main::$_0>, pplx::task<web::http::http_response> (Concurrency::streams::basic_ostream<unsigned char>)>::operator()(Concurrency::streams::basic_ostream<unsigned char>&&) in webclient.cpp.o
  "web::uri_builder::append_query(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool)", referenced from:
      web::uri_builder& web::uri_builder::append_query<char [37]>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const (&) [37], bool) in webclient.cpp.o
  "web::uri_builder::to_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::__function::__func<main::$_0, std::__1::allocator<main::$_0>, pplx::task<web::http::http_response> (Concurrency::streams::basic_ostream<unsigned char>)>::operator()(Concurrency::streams::basic_ostream<unsigned char>&&) in webclient.cpp.o
  "web::uri::encode_impl(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::function<bool (int)> const&)", referenced from:
      web::uri_builder& web::uri_builder::append_query<char [37]>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const (&) [37], bool) in webclient.cpp.o
  ...
```

The `::__1` is LLVM's anonymous namespace. What you see above is a symptom of mixing and matching runtimes. I.e., inconsistent use of `-stdlib=XXX`.

You need to build everything with GNU's gear and `-stlib=libstdc++`; or you need to build everything with LLVM's gear and `-stdlib=libc++`.

What I found works best to avoid user problems and questions is to always use LLVM's gear on OS X and iOS. I.e., always use `-stdlib=libc++`.

---

***Updated Question***:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::this_thread::interruption_point()", referenced from:
      boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&) in webclient.cpp.o
      boost::condition_variable::do_wait_until(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&, timespec const&) in webclient.cpp.o
  "boost::chrono::steady_clock::now()", referenced from:
      pplx::details::event_impl::wait(unsigned int) in webclient.cpp.o
  "boost::chrono::system_clock::now()", referenced from:
      pplx::details::event_impl::wait(unsigned int) in webclient.cpp.o
  "boost::detail::get_current_thread_data()", referenced from:
      boost::detail::interruption_checker::interruption_checker(_opaque_pthread_mutex_t*, _opaque_pthread_cond_t*) in webclient.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

For the updated question, see [Using and building the library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/thread/build.html) in the Boost user guide. You have to build Boost with threading support (does Brew do that?), and you have to link to the Boost threading library (is CMake doing that?).

I don't use Boost or CMake, so I can't take you any further. Sorry about that.

---

> ```
> set(OPT_CPPFLAGS "-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/libiconv/include")
> ```

I'm no CMake expert, but this could be problematic, too. `CPPFLAGS` is the flags for the C preprocessor. They may or may not be added to the `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`.

You should definitely call-out the same flags for `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` just in case. If this were an Autotools project, then I would change the *should* to a *must*. But like I said, I'm no CMake expert by any strecth of the imagination.

---

And one final note... You can't use CMake to build OpenSSL. You have to [configure an build it yourself](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation). Once installed, you can reference the installed OpenSSL in a `find-openssl.cmake` type fashion.

The reasons are not readily apprent... OpenSSL's `Configure` script sets up some important settings that are used later in the build process. The two most important files for the settings are [`<opensslconf.h>` and `<bn.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25530429/608639).

You can also get an impressive speed improvement (2x to 4x) for Diffie-Hellman and Elliptic Curves on Intel-based x86_64 machines by `Configure`ing with [`enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Configure_Options).

Comment: When I added -stdlib=libc++ it converted it to -lc++.  Was that expected?

Comment: I should say to the linker flags; it still got the same Undefined symbols

Comment: @AmazingGrace - *"... it converted it to -lc++"* - I don't recall seeing that happen, but it sounds OK. LLVM's `libc++` would be specified as `-lc++` when represented as  a linker option. But what usually happens is, you link via the compiler. The compiler knows to link when it sees the `-o myprog.exe` or `-shared mylib.dylib` option. The compiler than adds `-lc++` for you.

Comment: @AmazingGrace - *"I should say to the linker flags; it still got the same Undefined symbols"* - The runtime library is both a compiler and linker option. You need it in both places, and not just link.

Comment: I misspoked meant the compiler flag and it added like you said the -lc++ flag for me.  Been staying at this issue for to many hours.  Thanks so much now down to just 4 symbol references.

Comment: *"Been staring at this issue for to many hours..."* - I know what you mean. I've built many packages from sources on OS X, like Git and cURL. They will suck the life out of you, especially when learning LLVM and OSX-isms.

Comment: I not building any of the libraries I used brew to install so I wouldn't have to do that.

Comment: I not a CMAKE either my understanding the set creates a variable with that name. It's the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS that is initialize by the variables ${} and string. I named them OPT because when brew install openssl and libiconv it warned by including them in the normal system directories would cause issues and if needed to use the flags.  I know the flags are working because at the beginning this code would not even compile.  Technicallly I'm not even doing ssl at this point.  The issue that is left seems to be boost.

Comment: @AmazingGrace - it looks like you lack Boost's threading library. Also see [How can I decode the boost library naming?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2715164) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: that link didn't help much I tried -lboost_thread but it rejects that name.

Comment: @AmazingGrace - Unfortunately, you've reached the limit of my knowledge because I don't use Boost, Brew or CMake. Since you are using Brew, maybe you should try [Is there a list of brew's install-able packages?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8833230/608639) to see if (1) Brew provides multithreaded Boost libraries, (2) you installed the multithreaded versions of the library and (3) what the multithreaded library's name is. Also see [Boost's thread group on Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11617047/608639), which seems closely related.